# Do I need session mode if I use desktop mode?

Tags: desktop, session

I found old mail in my mailbox:

```
Date: 2010-09-13 17:41:21+0300 Mon
(require 'session)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'session-initialize)
```

Now I am using `desktop` mode:

```
(setq desktop-base-file-name ".emacs.desktop")
(setq desktop-base-lock-name ".emacs.desktop.lock")
(when (eq system-type 'cygwin)
  (setq desktop-base-file-name ".emacs.desktop-cygwin")
  (setq desktop-base-lock-name ".emacs.desktop-cygwin.lock")
  )
(setq desktop-dirname user-emacs-directory)

(when (>= emacs-major-version 22)
  (require 'desktop)
  (add-to-list 'desktop-path desktop-dirname)
  (setq desktop-restore-frames nil)
  (desktop-save-mode 1)
  (setq
   desktop-globals-to-save
   (append
    '((file-name-history . 100)
      (compile-history . 100)
      (command-history . 100)
      (extended-command-history . 100)
      (shell-command-history . 100)
      (query-replace-history . 100)
      (regexp-history . 100)
      (grep-history . 100)
      (minibuffer-history . 100))
    desktop-globals-to-save))    )
```

`session` is provided by `/usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/emacs-goodies-el/session.el` so it is not built-in.

Do I get any benefits from `session.el`?